# Cocos2d transferring a variable from one class to another class

Tags: objective-c, ios, class, cocos2d-iphone

At the moment I am trying to use an integer to declare whether or not a setting is enabled or disabled, the issue that I am facing is trying to use the variable in another class so as that I can transfer the setting to be used in the actual game. My question is how can I do this? If you have an answer could you also give an example of how this would be implemented.

Thanks for your time,

Christian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Playing off of what Morion said, take a look at these: [Singletons](http://getsetgames.com/2009/08/30/the-objective-c-singleton/)

They are good for things like this. They will allow you to create a "global class" from which you can access variables like this: `[[MySingleton instance] myVariable];` from anywhere in your  game. The link will explain how to set one up.

Singletons are probably a bit more organized and easy to use, but Morion's way is most likely faster.

Answer (score 0):

If it is global variable, you can create some kind of GlobalData class with needed instance.

If it is just a setting for your game, you can create class/structure that will store needed settings and then pass this class/structure to the constructor of your level. Smth like

```
GameSetting setting; // some structure
setting.numberOfEnemies = 10;
setting.anyOtherField = 1;
....
CCScene* gameScene = [MyGameScene sceneWithSetting:setting];
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:gameScene];
```